# Hiding JavaScript key on parse.com web

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform

I've got a new project which is using a Prase.com. So I thought great ! I will learn something new. So I decide to use Javascript to connect to database. I read a docs on parse.com and they say connect to your app using:

```
 Parse.initialize("$PARSE_APPLICATION_ID", "$PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY");
```

What? In public JS file I've to put a ID and key ?

How to hide it or protect from inappropriate use? I don't want to use Settings options and uncheck some options. I want to hide it from JS file. Maybe I need to use php to connect to app and then use JavaScript ? If so how can I do this?

Comment: The client keys are subject to the currently logged in user. The Master key is the one you want to keep well hidden. just make sure you set the proper ACLs on your objects and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot hide your keys from your clients. All your application keys (expect for the Master key) are NOT meant to be secrets and cannot be hidden from end users. This is clearly explained in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#security-client-vs-server):

> When an app first connects to Parse, it identifies itself with an
>   Application ID and a Client key (or REST Key, or .NET Key, or
>   JavaScript Key, depending on which platform you're using). These are
>   not secret and by themselves they do not secure an app. These keys are
>   shipped as a part of your app, and anyone can decompile your app or
>   proxy network traffic from their device to find your client key. This
>   exploit is even easier with JavaScript — one can simply "view source"
>   in the browser and immediately find your client key.

You need to follow Parse security model and use ACL, CLPs and cloud code to protect your data from being accessed by unauthorised users.